# Angular ui-router redirects back to parent state with nested views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a router in Angular:

```
var scenarioManagementModule = angular.module( 'scenarioManagementModule', ['ngResource', 'scenarioModule'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state( 'scenario_management', {
        url:         '/scenario_management',
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller:  function( $scope, $state ) {
            $state.transitionTo('scenario_management.scenarios', { reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true });
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state( 'scenario_management.scenarios', {
        url:         '/scenarios',
        templateUrl: '/scenarios.html',
        controller:  'ScenarioListController',
        resolve:     {
            scenarios_data:  function( $stateParams, Scenario ){
                return Scenario.list();
            }
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state( 'scenario_management.scenarios.create', {
        url:            '/create',
        templateUrl:    '/scenario.create.html',
        controller:     'ScenarioCreateController',
    });
}]);
```

My views are set up correctly. All parent templates have their ui-views at the right place, and when I try to access the create page by pasting the url in the browser, it works perfectly.

However, when I programmatically try to invoke the create state with the following code, something strange happens:

```
$state.transitionTo('scenario_management.scenarios.create', $stateParams, { reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true });
```

Through console.log, I can see the create state being loaded as desired, however when this state finishes loading, immediately afterwards its parent state starts loading again. As a result, the create state disappears again. And also according to the browser's url, I am now in the parent state again.

Am I doing something wrong? Can someone tell me what's going on, and how can I make sure that the create state stays loaded in?

Comment: I think you should use state.go. It's based on transitionTo. I don't see any problem in your config.

Comment: from doc: Low-level method for transitioning to a new state. $state.go uses transitionTo internally. $state.go is recommended in most situations. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: I tried that, but that didn't resolve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: In your first state you have `controller:  function( $scope, $state ) {
            $state.transitionTo('scenario_management.scenarios', { reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true });
        }` this is the reason. Try to delete it.

Comment: If you don't want load this state properly you can use abstract: true.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that was it.  Thank you very much! I suspect that the line transitionto was always fired off, causing the router to always go back to that state.

Comment: I wrote an answer. Could you mark it as correct to help other people find a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want load this state properly you can use abstract: true.